# Execute ms dos batch script from cruise control and pass variables

Tags: environment-variables, cruisecontrol.net, batch-file

I am trying to execute a msdos batch script from cruise control and pass some variables. I can execute the batch script fine but I can't access the environment variables in the batch script. Here's what my ccnet config file has:

```
<exec>
        <executable>myscript.BAT</executable>
        <environment>
            <variable name="var1" value="value1" />
            <variable name="var2" value="value2" />
        </environment>
</exec>
```

How can I access var1 and var2 in myscript.BAT? All I get when I do "%var1%" is blank.

Comment: Is it CruiseControl.NET or CruiseControl (Java)? Also, please specify version.

Comment: It is CruiseControl.NET. It is one of the older versions (1.2.1). Could that be an issue?

Comment: It's really hard to answer, there were numerous changes and fixes (that version is several years old) and I'm afraid not many people will be able to help you with it.

Comment: But is this the correct way of doing it for the newer versions?

Comment: Yes, that should work in new versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in your values as parameters and reference `var1` and `var2` by `$1` and `$2` respectively.

Comment: Yes I thought about it too. The problem with that is there are six parameters and couple of them are paths. I think it is going to look messy. Moreover, I have to reference them with numbers in the batch script and this can be tedious to keep track of.